# LInq to SQL - Partial Class - C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a system with 2 different projects, one is called LINQ_Extensions and the other is ORM_Linq.

On ORM_Linq i have the LINQ diagram with the SQL tables "converted" in clases. One of the Class is called "Tipos_Pago"

In the other project i have another class (partial class) "Tipos_Pago". I want to use the method OnValidate to validate the properties include in the class "Tipos_Pago", so i create this partial class.

In the 2 projects i put the same NameSpace "ORM_Linq"(I changed the NameSpace of the project "LINQ_Extensions" to have the same of the project "ORM_Linq")

After those chages, Visual Studio give me this error:

**Error 1 No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method 'ORM_Linq.Tipos_Pago.OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction)' C..\Tipos_Pago.cs 13 22 Extensiones_Linq**

I don't have any Idea of what happend, can someone help me?

Thanks, sorry for my poor english

This is the code in the partial class:

```
namespace ORM_Linq
{
    public partial class Tipos_Pago
    {

        partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
        {
         //Valid code
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW; if they *are* in the same project, if you have (for example) `Tipos_Pago.dbml`, try **not** to create a file (for your partial classes) called `Tipos_Pago.cs` - there is a bug in the code-generator (fixed in 4.0) that means this gets painful. Using **any other** file name (except `Tipos_Pago.designer.cs`, obviously) is fine.

Comment: @Marc -- I haven't been bit by this bug and I always give it the same name as the class.  Do you have more details or a link you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implement a partial across 2 projects, since they have to be compiled together, the `partial` declarations must all be in the same project.

This same rule applies for methods and classes.

Comment: ok, thanks, i change the project because i have circular ref problem, i don't what to do, maybe i have to change other code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your partial implementation in the same project as the designer-generated classes.

From the Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(VS.80).aspx):

> All partial-type definitions meant to
>   be parts of the same type must be
>   defined in the same assembly and the
>   same module (.exe or .dll file).
>   Partial definitions cannot span
>   multiple modules.